# how can I insert multiples record and save data in two tables in rails json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

hello soem body can help me with one example in rails to do a post request to save multiples records and sabe data in diferents tables in json

```
{   
  "post":
  {
    "title":"Titlea 2",
    "body":"body of the post 2"
  }
  "comment":[
    {
      "title":"Title 2",
      "body":"body of the post 2"
    },
    {
      "title":"Title 2",
      "body":"body of the post 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

actually I have the basic scaffold code im very new in rails

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
    render json: @comments
  end
  def show
    render json: @comment
  end

  # POST /comments
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment
    else
      render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :comment)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you add your current code for saving single records?

Comment: Just add is pending to add the other table but i dont know how to save data in two diferent tables and save multiple data

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with Post and Comment? 
Could you set up your form for Post / Post Controller, and then accept nested attributes for comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do with Post and Comment? 
Could you set up your form for Post / PostController, and then accept nested attributes for Comments?

Maybe check out Simple Form's nested models. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Also, posting your Comment / Post models and their association would be helpful.